# Passing file as base64 to Primefaces' remote command

Tags: jsf, async-await, primefaces

I have an array of File objects on my client side and I'm trying to send b64 value of that files to managed bean.

HTML:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="convertToPdfa" actionListener="#{bean.convertFile}" />
```

Bean method:

```
public String convertFile() {
    String index = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("index"); // not empty
    String data = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("data"); // not empty
    String retry = Boolean.parseBoolean(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("retry")); // empty
    return "";
}
```

Javascript:

```
convertAll: async function (noOfFiles) {
    for (let i = 0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {
        await sendFileDataAndConvert(i);
    }
},
sendFileDataAndConvert: async function (index) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(getFile(index));
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });

    // wait until the promise returns us a value
    let result = await promise;

    // "Now it's done!"
    console.log(result); // result is not empty, file is converted
    convertToPdfa([{name: 'index', value: index}, {name: 'data', result}, {name: 'retry', value: false}]);
}
```

Now since I'm using async function to convert File to base64, I need to wait for the result to be available before I invoke remote command. I'm guessing that parameters passed to remote command are set before the result is available? Is remote command invoked before result is available? Because when I try to read parameters in managed bean method, `data` is empty, but the other two parameters are not empty. I don't exactly understand what's going on here. I'm trying to wait for the result using `async/await` mechanism, but it looks like I'm missing something.

How can I achieve that remote command parameters are set after async function is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out it was a typo. Instead of

```
convertToPdfa([{name: 'index', value: index}, {name: 'data', result}, {name: 'retry', value: false}]);
```

it should be

```
convertToPdfa([{name: 'index', value: index}, {name: 'data', value: result}, {name: 'retry', value: false}]);
```